# Как вставить переменную в селектор jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var id = 4;
$('.building[data-id="тут должно быть значение из id"]')
```

Как мне найти элемент с атрибутом, значение которого у меня есть в переменной? Другими словами, как подставить значение переменной в селектор jQuery? Спасибо.

Comment: var id = 4;  $('.building[data-id="'+ id +'"]')

Comment: это не работает, проверял

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте [шаблонные литералы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```js
var id = 4;
console.log($(`.building[data-id="${id}"]`).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="building" data-id="2">ID2</div>
<div class="building" data-id="4">Нужный</div>
```

Comment: интересно, а почему вариант работает только с косыми ковычками?)

Comment: @АлександрЛиссов: Вы по ссылке переходили? Читали? Э-эх...

Comment: я не заметил ее)

Comment: понял фишку, спасибо